# Setting the value for the name attribute with cforms input fields

Tags: plugin-cforms

How do I set the name attribute of an input field using cforms2 ? As in:

```
<input type="text" name="[my_input_name]" />
```

I'm using `single line of text` as the type, and `Email Address||` under the field name category, but I don't understand how to set the name attribute.

I need to do this because the form will hit a custom endpoint that expects parameters to have certain names.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Under the `Core Form Admin` sections in the options, there's an option called `Use custom input fields names & ids`, with the following note:

> This feature replaces the default NAMEs/IDs (e.g. cf_field_12) with custom ones, either derived from the field label you have provided or by specifically declaring it via [id:XYZ],e.g. Your Name[id:the-name]. This will for instance help to feed data to third party systems (requiring certain input field names in the $_POST variable).